# Copy formatting in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, formatting

In Illustrator, is it possible to copy formatting? Or, for that matter, redo formatting just made?

I'm thinking of the "format brush" from Microsoft programs, for example, which are very convenient to copy formatting, not content.

Let's say for example I have several single lines. I change the stroke on one of them, even the stroke weight and colour. I select my next line and want to just REDO the same thing. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

This is what the **Graphic Styles** panel is for.

Drag a formatted object to the **Graphic Styles Panel** (Window > Graphic Styles)

When you want to change a different object to have the same appearance, select the object, then merely click the style in the **Graphic Styles Panel**.

[image]

Graphic Styles in Illustrator are similar to Paragraph styles, but for object appearance (This is also similar to the Object Styles panel in Adobe InDesign).

Answer (score 4):

Sure, just use the Eyedropper tool (<kbd>`I`</kbd>). Unlike Photoshop it picks up appearance attributes and doesn't just sample color...

[image]

It works on live type too...

[image]

You can even double click the tool to choose what it will and will not sample...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Format your original object then use the 'Window → Appearance' panel and drag the initial formatting to other objects.

Comment: to other objects on the layer panel or straight to the artboard? neither works, when i try it...